# Get folder path with applescript reuse it in a .sh file

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I'm trying to script a workflow that can be used by multiple users. A user needs to specify a location to a dropbox folder, which path needs to be reused in shell and applescript.

The goal of the workflow is to automate the setup of a monitored folder that watches for file changes (With the help of launchd). When a change is detected, a shell script should be triggered that runs: npm run generate in the parent of the watched folder.

I managed to create the workflow with a .sh file and local paths, but now I want to update it so the paths need to be chosen by the user that runs the script, since these paths differ per user. See the steps for the workflow

1. Choose dropbox folder location
2. Create executable shell script file in that folder
3. Add code to that file

3a: Add applescript which uses the path of the chosen folder to run a npm command
 3b: Create a launchd file to the users LanchAgents folder (Mac users only)
 3c: Add content to that launchd file with the path of the chosen folder

4. launch launchd file.

```sh
    touch ~/Dropbox\ \(Folder\ name\)/folder/generate-icon-script.sh && echo "
    osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"
            do script \"cd ~/Dropbox\\\ \\\(Folder\\\ name\\\)/folder/ && /usr/local/bin/npm run generate\"
            delay 10
            quit
        end tell'"  >> ~/Dropbox\ \(Folder\ name\)/folder/generate-icon-script.sh 
    && chmod a+x ~/Dropbox\ \(Folder\ name\)/folder/generate-icon-script.sh 
    && touch ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.icons.daemon.plist 
    && echo "

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>com.icons.daemon.plist</string>
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>sh</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>~/Dropbox\\ \\(Folder\\ name\\)//folder/generate-icon-script.sh</string>
            </array>
            <array>
                <string>~/Dropbox (Folder name)/folder/input</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
    " >> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.icons.daemon.plist &&
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.icons.daemon.plist
```

To let the user determine the path, I created an applescript that prompts the user to select the correct location of the dropbox folder. I managed to create the .sh file in the dropbox folder and echo some contents to it. The problem I'm facing is that the path that I'm saving cannot be used in the terminal.

```
set myLocation to (choose folder with prompt "Choose the location to the Icons Folder") # Get location to save the file
set myLocationPOSIX to the POSIX path of myLocation
do shell script "touch " & quoted form of myLocationPOSIX & "/test.sh"
do shell script "chmod a+x " & quoted form of myLocationPOSIX & "/test.sh"
do shell script "echo cd " & quoted form of myLocationPOSIX & " \\&\\& /usr/local/bin/npm run generate >> " & quoted form of myLocationPOSIX & "test.sh"
```

How do I save the path so it can be used in my workflow? Any help will be greatly apcodeciated!

I expect the output of the echo to be:
`cd Users/name/Dropbox\\ \\(Folder\\ name\\ )/folder/ && /usr/local/bin/npm run generate`

But I get: 
`cd /Users/name/Dropbox (Folder name)/folder/ && /usr/local/bin/npm run generate`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `quoted form of` quotes an entire string, it doesn't escape individual characters.

Comment: brdnb - **1)** Where in your _com.icons.daemon.plist_ file are you specifying the pathname of the folder that you want to watch for changes, (i.e. the folder you want to watch for any new files/folders that are added, moved, or deleted) ? I can't see a `<key>WatchPaths</key>` specified anywhere. **2)** What is the `<string>~/Dropbox (Folder name)/folder/input</string>` part currently in your _.plist_? **3)** Is the AppleScript, (i.e. the one that prompts the user to select the correct location of the Dropbox folder), also going to invoke the shell script after the user select the folder ?

Comment: @RobC Think I accidentally removed the Watchpath key. Got It working by the solution below!

Comment: Good that you found a solution - albeit not a nice one. Btw, the `generate-icon-script.sh` file in your example seems unnecessary... you could run `npm run generate` from the `.plist` file instead? Also I wasn't sure what you meant by _"monitored folder that watches for file changes"_ I thought that you may have meant when a file was modified, (i.e. when some one edits and existing file), but I now realize you only want the `npm run ...` to be invoked when someone adds, moves, or deletes a file from the target folder.

Comment: @RobC That would actually be better indeed. I'm trying it as we speak, but I'm not able to run multiple commands. Got any ideas? Ive updated my original post with the new launchd file.

Comment: brdnd - It's best to ask a new question and reference this one. I also suggest clicking the `edited` button below your post and _"rollback"_ to it's original form because the accepted answer now doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: brdnd - I've rolledback your question to an earlier version so that the accepted answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in the shell, I think, is either this:

```
/Users/name/Dropbox\ (Folder\ name)/folder/
```

or this:

```
'/Users/name/Dropbox (Folder name)/folder/'
```

Either will parse correctly. What you're getting now is the latter, through `quoted form of myLocationPOSIX`. It should work, even though you're not seeing what you expect. Getting the former is doable using text item delimiters, but it's a bit of a PITA:

```
set tid to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to " "
set piecesList to text items of myLocationPOSIX
set text item delimiters to "\\ "
set newLocationPath to piecesList as text
set text item delimiters to tid
```

That code breaks the location path up at the spaces, and then joins it together again using a '\ '. Gets the job done, but it's not pretty...

Is there some specific reason you need to escape the individual spaces rather than quote the entire path?